# Is Zoom possible without a previous Select

Tags: excel, vba

In order to change the zoom on a specific sheet I'm doing the following:

```
mySheet.Select
Excel.ActiveWindow.Zoom = 80
```

In production Excel code I try to avoid using `Select` - is that possible in the above?

Comment: No it isn't. This is one of the rare occasions where you need to select.

Comment: strange they didn't overload (is this correct term?) this method for the worksheet object

Comment: Strange? Yes and no. You can have multiple windows open on the same sheet, so you can't really set a zoom for the sheet - it has to be a property of the Window.

Comment: (@Rory not so strange now you've explained)